# Jquery detect div scroll bar scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var Height = 600;

    $('#message_container').scroll(function(){
        if ($('#message_container').scrollTop() > Height){
            alert('up');

        }else{
            alert('down');
        }
    });
```

I have div `overflow-y:auto`, it fetch out 10 messages per time.

I try to use jquery scroll up to fetch out more message.

`div` height is 600px; while im testing, **it keep alert down even i scroll up**, anyone know why?

Here is Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/asEmz/

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: try to get the value of $('#message_container').scrollTop(). I don't think this returns a value.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asEmz/

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/D9fGG/1/

Comment: actually what i need is when the scroll hit top, not it alert when us scroll a bit

Comment: It looks like you need only when you reach at top... http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/a5bD2/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from JQuery

> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that
>   are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is
>   at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will
>   be 0

so test with 0 [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/a5bD2/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $("#message_container").scrollTop($("#message_container")[0].scrollHeight);

    var Height = 600;

    $('#message_container').scroll(function(){
        if ($('#message_container').scrollTop() == 0){
            $('#status').html('up');
            //alert('up');

        }else{
            $('#status').html('down');
            //alert('down');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
$("#message_container").scrollTop($("#message_container")[0].scrollHeight);

var Height = 60;

$('#message_container').scroll(function(){
    if ($('#message_container').scrollTop() < Height){
        alert('up');

    }else{
        alert('down');
    }
});

});
```